# Applying remote changes onto local, git pull overwrites files, another way than stashing?

Tags: git, git-pull

I am working on a local version of a site pulled from a remote repo and made changes to the site. The partner working on it has also made changes and I need to pull them onto my local version without overwriting the files I have created or changed.

I know that I can stash my changes and then access them later, but is this the best approach?

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?. select an answer as correct or post your own

Answer (score 2):

If you have both made changes to the same file(s), source control software should where possible merge the two, accepting both changes.

If it fails to perform a merge then the file should be highlighted as conflicted, where manual intervention is required to resolve the differences.

Comment: so if I do git pull remotename backend it should ask really if I want to overwrite them? I have already committed my changes but I have not pushed them yet and I do not want to.

Comment: No, doing a pull implies that you want to accept the changes of others. If their changes conflict with yours, the changes will remain unaccepted until you manually correct them. Also, the danger of not pushing when you are working collaboratively is that the other user will not be aware of any changes you have made and may not code accordingly, leading to further possible issues

Answer (score 2):

git pull is basically a shortcut for two operations:

1. `git fetch` which downloads the history from the remote.
2. `git merge` which merges the new history in the current branch.

It is step two where the changes from the repository get merged into your local files, because you ask git to.

The question is, why do you need to have those changes. Do you want to inspect them?

If you only want the history, without merging it, you can use plain `git fetch <remote>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you say "you are working" on a local copy, I recommend commiting changes in the local repository, periodically and sporadically.

Then you can do a `git fetch origin` (assuming origin is your remote) and a `git rebase origin/master` (assuming you want the latest changes from master).

Then you would have, let's say, 20 git commits on top of the changes on the remote, but you can always do a `git rebase -i`, which allows you to move around, rename and *squash* multiple commits into one, when you are ready to move them anywhere outside your *local* development branch.

There are purists out there that say history shouldn't be messed with, but I think that doing this on a specialized and local *development* branch is perfectly acceptable. This way, you still have a local history for the feature you are developing, with all the goodies it enables, history you're not yet ready to show to the world.

The alternative is to do `git stash; git pull origin/master; git stash pop` or something similar.

Also, note that in both cases you would have to resolve any existing conflicts. If what you want in case of a conflict is to keep your copy before *pulling* the changes from the remote, you can resolve the conflict by just keeping your local version of the file. But I doubt this is what anyone would need, it could break things.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull on to your existing branch his commits will be merged with yours or you will be prompted with conflicts or both.

however he could checkout his branch on to a new branch.

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

and push it to origin newbranch

```
git push origin newbranch
```

then you can `git fetch`

and safely checkout to that branch from your side without loosing your work.

```
git checkout newbranch
```

later on  you could merge his branch with yours if needed.